# jCarousel more sliders per page

Tags: jcarousel

I use jCarousel for my project. I need three or more sliders on page. But it work ok when on page is only one slider. I tried some magic with JS script, but it doesn't help.

Look my sliders code:

```
<h3>My Queue</h3>
  <div id="myque" class="jcarousel-wrapper">
    <div id="myque" class="jcarousel" data-jcarousel="true">
        <ul id="myque" style="left: -100px; top: 0px;">  
          <li><img src="slides/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1"><h4><a href="#">Titlu nr.1</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img2.jpg" alt="Image 2"><h4><a href="#">Titlu numarul 1</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img3.jpg" alt="Image 3"><h4><a href="#">Numărul trei</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img4.jpg" alt="Image 4"><h4><a href="#">Încercarea patru</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img5.jpg" alt="Image 5"><h4><a href="#">5</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img6.jpg" alt="Image 6"><h4><a href="#">Șase</a></h4></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="myque" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a id="myque" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>

  <h3>Feature topic: <b>Labor Day</b></h3>
  <div id="feature" class="jcarousel-wrapper">
    <div id="feature" class="jcarousel" data-jcarousel="true">
        <ul id="feature" style="left: -100px; top: 0px;">  
          <li><img src="slides/img1.jpg" alt="Image 1"><h4><a href="#">Titlu nr.1</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img2.jpg" alt="Image 2"><h4><a href="#">Titlu numarul 1</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img3.jpg" alt="Image 3"><h4><a href="#">Numărul trei</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img4.jpg" alt="Image 4"><h4><a href="#">Încercarea patru</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img5.jpg" alt="Image 5"><h4><a href="#">5</a></h4></li>
          <li><img src="slides/img6.jpg" alt="Image 6"><h4><a href="#">Șase</a></h4></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a id="feature" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a id="feature" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added id at each div, #feature and #myque. Then i tried this JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feature').jcarousel();
    $('#myque').jcarousel();
});
</script>
```

But it doesnt help. No one of slider doesnt work when they'r together.

**Oficial site:** http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/ dont say anything about multipliyng of slider. I can post files if u can help.

Answer (score 0):

Why You added same id value to multiple tags? Remove duplicated id's, id values should be unique in whole document.